# White noise and Gaussian random processes: properties

Tags: random, stationary-processes

I know that white noise random processes and Gaussian random processes are different things. I also know that white noise random processes are always stationary, at least in a wide sense. Anyway I have still some doubts.

1. Are all white noise processes also ergodic?
2. Are all Gaussian random processes stationary? and ergodic?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You need to look at the exact definitions for both processes.  When I worked on them, they were the same (stationary Gaussian).

Comment: Were they the same always? in all cases?
Maybe, in practice, real signals nearly satisfy both stationary and gaussian conditions?!

Comment: Anyway, also looking at the exact definition for Gaussian processes, it does not explicitly seems that these processes are always stationary. On the contrary, it seems that stationarity could be an additional characteristic to the basic characteristics of Gaussian processes.

Comment: Not all Gaussian processes are stationary.  However in my usage white noise and stationary Gaussian processes were the same.

Comment: what was your usage?

Comment: Derivation of second moment of zeroes of these processes.

Comment: These terms can be distinguished by context.  Gaussian processes are mathematical terms for certain stochastic processes.  Random noise is an engineering term and the process is mathematically represented by stationary Gaussian.  When the noise spectrum is flat, it is called white noise, otherwise "colored".

Comment: Well, maybe random noise is always statistically described in that way, i.e. as a Gaussian white noise. 
But I'm studying the random response of a structural system. Specifically, the response to white noise excitations (not strictly Gaussian). Here, I've found some confusion concerning the white noise definition: sometimes it was defined as a collection of independent random variables, sometimes these random variables were assumed uncorrelated (which is different from "indipendent")...

Comment: ...I think that this problem arises because the white noise can be defined in different ways, which are slightly different among them. Do you know something about this topic?

Comment: I am a mathematician, not an engineer.  The work I did was with electrical engineers concerned with noise in em signals.  Your area seems to be civil engineering and I have no idea about the procsses involved.

Comment: ok, thank you the same